# It does not work for gradle to execute specific tests from the command-line

Tags: command-line, gradle, filter

For gradle, executing specific tests from the command-line should work since version 1.0 (or 1.1), but it does not work on version 2.7.

I tried below commands:

```
gradle test --tests com.mk.myfirstapp.MyUT
```

gradle outputs 'unknown cmdline options':

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :app:test from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

* Try:
Run gradle help --task :app:test to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.505 secs
```

The same for another command like

```
gradle -Dtest.single=abc test
```

Does anyone know it is a bug or my misuse? Thanks.

**more details**

I did the same as Opel(below), but I have a difference result. What is wrong with my gradle then :-?

```
mk@mk-desktop:~/StudioProjects/MyFirstApp$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-09-14 07:26:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     c41505168da69fb0650f4e31c9e01b50ffc97893

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.5.0-44-generic amd64

mk@mk-desktop:~/StudioProjects/MyFirstApp$ gradle test --tests BlogFeedEndpointSpec 
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20150407-jdk16 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20150407-jdk16 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :app:test from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

* Try:
Run gradle help --task :app:test to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.574 secs
```

Comment: Which version of gradle are you using?

Answer (score 6):

I also received the error: *Unknown command-line option '--tests'.*

Running the suggested command following the error turned out to be useful. In your case:

> Run gradle help --task :app:test to get task usage details.

I'm on a multi-module Android project, and the first project/task it tried to run is registered as:

```
Type
    Task (org.gradle.api.Task)
Description
    Run unit tests for all variants.
```

The problem for me was this task runs on **all variants**, and that the `--tests` parameter is unavailable on `org.gardle.api.Task`.

A solution for Android is to run a specific variant task, e.g. `testRelease`, which is registered as:

```
Type
     AndroidUnitTest (com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidUnitTest)

Options
     --debug-jvm     Enable debugging for the test process. The process is started suspended and listening on port 5005.

     --fail-fast     Stops test execution after the first failed test.

     --tests     Sets test class or method name to be included, '*' is supported.

Description
     Run unit tests for the release build.
```

`./gradlew testRelease --tests '*.SomeFilter'` thus worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`--tests` option is correctly recognized in gradle 2.7:

```
➜  backend git:(master) gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-09-14 07:26:16 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     c41505168da69fb0650f4e31c9e01b50ffc97893

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.4 x86_64

➜  backend git:(master) gradle test --tests BlogFeedEndpointSpec 
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [BlogFeedEndpointSpec]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.88 secs
```

Comment: Thank for Opal's inputs, I find out why mine is diff with his. **Now I can work around**. In brief, "gradle test --tests classname" reports "invalid options"; but "gradle testDebugUnitTest --test classname" works fine, and "gradle testReleaseUnitTest --test classname" also works. but I can not explain why "gradle test" does **NOT** work in my env (a studio-generated my first app).

Comment: Sure, as far as I see you've added custom tasks - that may be the reason. Maybe sth is misconfigured.

Comment: This is still the same behaviour - doesn't work with ./gradlwe test --tests myClass even today in 2021...

Comment: "gradle testDebugUnitTest --tests classname" worked for me; actually, since I have multiple modules and variants the full command would be:                              
gradle :myModule:test[variant]DebugUnitTest -- tests classname                                thanks!

Comment: @Opal I don't think anything is "misconfigured", although one could argue all of Android development is one big "misconfiguration". :) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220948/590790): some custom Android tasks, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. The cause turned out to be that i had multiple sub-projects. Running

```
$ ./gradlew test --tests com.test.test
```

did not work with the unrecognised "--tests" error, but running

```
$ ./gradlew -p projectWithJUnitTestts test --test com.test.test
```

ran ok.

Comment: What is `projectWithJUnitTestts` ?

Comment: Replace projectWithJUnitTestts with the name of your own project (the one you want to test).

Comment: When you have multiple sub-projects, it should simply try to run `test` on all of them; this is not really the problem. What _likely happened_ is that one of your subprojects had a `test` task registered, which did not support the `--tests` parameter. See [my answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220948/590790).